# │ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

im facing this issue. here is my android level build.gradle file

How to remove the error? i tried using solutions on chapgpt and on stack overflow but nothing help

```
Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update D:\Flutter projects\freelancer_clone\android\build.gradle:                          │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'      

e: C:/Users/Saif/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b57de42a201255910bed3fe14c9241d4/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = "1.9.23"
    repositories {
        google() // Required for accessing Google's Maven repository for Firebase dependencies
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"



    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my app level build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


android {
    namespace "com.example.freelancer_clone"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.freelancer_clone"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i tried invalidate cache but nothing helped. tried changing kotlin versions to lower versions but it didnt helped.
tried chatgpt and stack overflow but nothing helped

Comment: Terrible unhelpful title. Check [ask]. Did you see the error message? "Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin." What happened wen you upgraded that plugin?

Comment: i didnt helped, i upgraded to latest 1.9.23 version but still its showing me to upgrade to latest kotlin version